# Scraping text into a <span> class with puppeteer-sharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I'm currently trying to recover text between `<span>` tags on an HTML page with Puppeteer .NET but I can’t. Here’s the part I'm trying to recover:

```
<span class="nbPoints">12</span>
```

I have already tried the function `EvaluateFunction` but I get nothing by trying to print it in the console

```
var strValueEst = await page.EvaluateFunctionAsync(
  "()=>document.querySelector('#path > path > nbPoints').textContent"
);
```

I no longer have the exact Java request in mind but that must not be the problem because I copy it via inspect the element and copy the full path JS (in Chrome).

Comment: Can you share a little bit more of the HTML you want to scrap? It's not clear how that selector you get a proxy element.

Comment: @hardkoded Hello thank you for your answer, my example may not be very clear, this part will be clearer, this is the second element that I am trying to obtain, it is a number of points.
here is the code which is contained in a <div> itself in a <div>:   
https://ibb.co/rw1xnPc                                                                                                            Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow and can't find how to put code in a comment

Comment: Are you sure that the selector will work?

Comment: @hardkoded I think the selector is ok, I extract it from inspect the element, right click, copy and copy the JS path.
I then replace what is after => with: document.querySelector ("# loyaltyProgramZone> div> div.loyalty-program-left> p.nb-total-points> span.nbPoints"). Thank you again for your help

Comment: When I enter it in the console it returns me: <span class="nbPoints">12</span>. It's so strange

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "innerText" except "textContent".

```cs
var strValueEst = await page.EvaluateFunctionAsync(
  "()=>document.querySelector('#path > path > nbPoints').innerText"
);
```